# Java - Checking sub array of chars ( contains some chars ? )

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, char

In my program i want to make sure that a string (char array) has just specific characters ( or specific counts of different chars and no more ) so i've written this code but here is a problem that it does not work correctly.

**Example** : if we have this char array for checking "hello" and we want to make sure that it just has "ollhevi" or less it should return true.

or a better one:
words = {'h','e','l','l','o'}
wanted = {'a','o','h','l'}
return false
because hello doesn't have 'a';

Just in theory it works.

**Code**

```
public boolean check(ArrayList<Character> words, ArrayList<Character> wanted) {
    for (Character chr : words) {
        if (wanted.contains(chr)) {
            wanted.remove(chr);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: your example is not clear...

Comment: Have you tried `wanted.removeAll(words); return wanted.isEmpty();`

Comment: yes but it does not work for my problem because count of chars is important for me for example wanted is 'a''a''b' but words are 'a''b''b' and this command removes all

Comment: Please show how you are creating the Lists. I've tested your method and it works. At least for your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So THAT was my big fault !!
Thanks for all answers
this is the solution

```
public boolean check(ArrayList<Character> words, ArrayList<Character> wanted) {
    for (Character chr : wanted) {
        words.remove(chr);
    }
    return words.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: always accept the the answer as correct to who gave the correct answer. That way people know it has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

run the for loop other way around.

run through all characters in wanted array, and see if they are present in words array. If any of the character is missing, then return false.

```
public boolean check(ArrayList<Character> words, ArrayList<Character> wanted) {
for (Character chr : wanted) {
    if (!words.contains(chr)) {
        return  false;
    } 
}
return true;
```

}

Comment: Count of specific types of chars are important for me as i said.

Comment: that you can add in the else part. create a map with <character, int> and increment the count everytime you encounter a valid variable in the map. Its not that hard.

Comment: No i mean count of a specific types not whole the string

Comment: thats why use map. you can store each character and its count in a map.

Comment: Cool idea but i have to process 100000 strings so i need fast way

Comment: Maps are really fast. And since your key is unique, its suggested to use that.

Comment: Yes you're right but here i think array lists are faster because if i want to use map first of all i have to search for chars then put them in map then i have to search char array with map but in array list i just search for chars and delete them

Comment: in arraylists you will have to implement a method to search for uniqueness. but in maps, the keys is always unique, hence overall time efficiency for a huge set or 100000 characters, as you said,  would be better with maps. just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer. Is more efficient to check if the char was removed. If not, check() can return false and stop iterate. Its faster.
Nottice thar List#remove(Object o) return true if the list containd the element.

```
public boolean check(ArrayList<Character> words, ArrayList<Character> wanted) {
    for (Character chr : wanted) {
        if(!words.remove(chr)){
           return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I can not do it. because may some of wanteds are not in words.